# Using Task to Setup a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, runtime-error, cross-thread

I am using Task() to offload work during the start of my application.  And it was working fine.  And then it wasn't...  If I've got it right, I am making a copy of 'SomeStatusradGridView'.  Which means I should be fine, except I get the following error:

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
MOSES.Logic.HumanResources.HumanResources.SomeStatusradGridView(Telerik.WinControls.UI.RadGridView) in HumanResources.cs
MOSES.Presentation.Main.Main_Load.AnonymousMethod__15_0() in Main.cs
[External Code]

Here is the code I am having the problem with:

```
public Main()
{
    Task<RadGridView> task2 = Task<RadGridView>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        return HumanResources.SetSomeStatusView(SomeStatusradGridView);
    });

    SomeMorkWork();

    SomeStatusradGridView = = task2.Result;
}

public static RadGridView SetSomeStatusView(RadGridView rgv)
{
    List<T> someList = new List<T>();
    rgv.DataSource = someList;
    return rgv;
}
```

Now, if I make the following change:

```
public static RadGridView SetSomeStatusView(RadGridView rgv)
{
    RadGridView fresh = new RadGridView();
    List<T> someList = new List<T>();
    fresh.DataSource = someList;
    return fresh;
}
```

I do not get the error, but that seems to indicate that a copy is not being made.  Any insight would be great.

Thank you!

Comment: You are creating a new List<T>() with no data contents.  The rgv is never being used.  When I use DGV I normally built my own DataTable and fill with the data from the database.  Then make the dt the DataSource for the DGV.

Comment: I do actually have records in the list, I just did not represent that here; I should have illustrated that.

Comment: Is List<T> really List<DataRow> or are you using a DataAdapter?

Comment: LINQ Entities object.

Comment: You have a classes of an Entity Model and need an interface to enumerate through the Model.  It is not a DataAdapter.

Comment: Thank you, but I've already solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

OK...  No sooner do I post the question and I discover the answer...

SomeStatusradGridView had Focus, or was Activated, in the Designer when it did not before.  I set focus to a different control.  Main() come up just fine.  Reset Focus back to SomeStatusradGridView and the error re-presented itself.

Comment: A DataGridView doesn't automatically repaint when data gets changed.  So the trick is to set the DataSource to null and then back to the source.